# TFlite Object Detection Model Not Outputting Correct Shape

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, tflite

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): WSL Linux Ubuntu 20.04 (although I've also tried on Linux Ubuntu 22.04)
TensorFlow installation (pip package or built from source): Pip package (t.
TensorFlow library (version, if pip package or github SHA, if built from source):
I built it with Conda and Python 3.9. Basically I install the environment in a Jupyter kernel and then use it to install the packages and eventually run the script.

```
# Install Miniconda
!apt install wget
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

# Update Conda
!conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y

# #Create a Python 3.9 environment
!conda create --name py39_environment python=3.9 -y

# # Initialize shell for Conda
!conda init bash

# # Activate the environment and check Python version
!source activate py39_environment && python --version
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate py39_environment && pip install tflite_model_maker
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate py39_environment && pip install -q pycocotools
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate py39_environment && pip install opencv-python-headless
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate py39_environment && pip uninstall -y tensorflow && pip install -q tensorflow==2.8.0
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate py39_environment && pip install ipykernel
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate py39_environment && pip install --upgrade numba llvmlite
```

Provide code to help us reproduce your issues using one of the following options:

train.py:

```
import numpy as np
import os

np.object = object
np.bool = bool
np.complex = complex

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)

label_map = {1: 'Plastic', 2: 'Trash'} 

train_images_dir = '/trashnet-training/pascal_voc/train/images'
train_annotations_dir = '/trashnet-training/pascal_voc/train/Annotations'
val_images_dir = '/trashnet-training/pascal_voc/valid/images/'
val_annotations_dir = '/trashnet-training/pascal_voc/valid/Annotations'
# test_images_dir =  '/trashnet-training/pascal_voc/train/Annotations'
# test_annotations_dir = '/trashnet-training/pascal_voc/train/Annotations'

train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    train_images_dir, train_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)

validation_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    val_images_dir, val_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)

# test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
#     test_images_dir, test_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)

spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite0')

model = object_detector.create(train_data=train_data, 
                               model_spec=spec, 
                               validation_data=validation_data, 
                               epochs=50, 
                               batch_size=10, 
                               train_whole_model=True)

model.evaluate(validation_data)

TFLITE_FILENAME = 'trained_model.tflite'
LABELS_FILENAME = 'model-labels.txt'

model.export(export_dir='.', tflite_filename=TFLITE_FILENAME, label_filename=LABELS_FILENAME,
             export_format=[ExportFormat.TFLITE, ExportFormat.LABEL])
```

test_model.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="trained_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()


input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
input_data = interpreter.get_tensor(input_details[0]['index'])
print(f"Input tensor: {input_data}")
print(f"Output tensor: {output_data}")


tf.lite.experimental.Analyzer.analyze(model_path="trained_model.tflite")
```

My dataset is in the Pascal VOC format with train and valid subfolders, each with their own images/ and Annotations/ folders. I've been able to train the model several times but whenever I put the resulting .tflite into the testing script, it doesn't product the shape it's supposed to. According to the TF documentation for the TFLite Object Detector export_tflite function here the output shape should be:

Four Outputs:
detection_boxes: a float32 tensor of shape [1, num_boxes, 4] with box
locations.
detection_classes: a float32 tensor of shape [1, num_boxes] with class
indices.
detection_scores: a float32 tensor of shape [1, num_boxes] with class
scores.
num_boxes: a float32 tensor of size 1 containing the number of detected
boxes.

The training seems to go fine, although somewhere along the way it warns me that:
2023-10-17 04:41:28.736735: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:803] Node 'resample_p7/PartitionedCall' has 1 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 3 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
Which is concerning. And I think part of the problem because when I run my testing script on the model the output tensors are all blank:

```
...
d_4;class_net/class-predict/bias11) shape:[1, 3, 3, 18], type:INT8
  T#583(Reshape) shape:[1, 14400, 2], type:INT8
  T#584(Reshape_1) shape:[1, 14400, 4], type:INT8
  T#585(Reshape_2) shape:[1, 3600, 2], type:INT8
  T#586(Reshape_3) shape:[1, 3600, 4], type:INT8
  T#587(Reshape_4) shape:[1, 900, 2], type:INT8
  T#588(Reshape_5) shape:[1, 900, 4], type:INT8
  T#589(Reshape_6) shape:[1, 225, 2], type:INT8
  T#590(Reshape_7) shape:[1, 225, 4], type:INT8
  T#591(Reshape_8) shape:[1, 81, 2], type:INT8
  T#592(concat) shape:[1, 19206, 2], type:INT8
  T#593(Sigmoid) shape:[1, 19206, 2], type:INT8
  T#594(Sigmoid1) shape:[1, 19206, 2], type:FLOAT32
  T#595(Reshape_9) shape:[1, 81, 4], type:INT8
  T#596(concat_1) shape:[1, 19206, 4], type:INT8
  T#597(tfl.dequantize) shape:[1, 19206, 4], type:FLOAT32
  T#598(StatefulPartitionedCall:3) shape:[], type:FLOAT32
  T#599(StatefulPartitionedCall:2) shape:[], type:FLOAT32
  T#600(StatefulPartitionedCall:1) shape:[], type:FLOAT32
  T#601(StatefulPartitionedCall:0) shape:[], type:FLOAT32

---------------------------------------------------------------
Your TFLite model has ‘1’ signature_def(s).

Signature#0 key: 'serving_default'
- Subgraph: Subgraph#0
- Inputs: 
    'images' : T#0
- Outputs: 
    'output_0' : T#601
    'output_1' : T#600
    'output_2' : T#599
    'output_3' : T#598

---------------------------------------------------------------
              Model size:    4444720 bytes
    Non-data buffer size:     799672 bytes (17.99 %)
  Total data buffer size:    3645048 bytes (82.01 %)
    (Zero value buffers):        256 bytes (00.01 %)
```

I've trained it several times with different formats but I just can't get the right output shapes, every time they're blank Could someone help me to understand why this is not working? Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.